# get all combinations words of a string

Tags: python

i want all combinations words of string "my first program"

Comment: Are you asking for every word you can spell with those letters? Or every way you can order those three words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> lst = "my first program".split()
>>> set(itertools.permutations(lst))

set([('first', 'my', 'program'),
     ('first', 'program', 'my'),
     ('my', 'first', 'program'),
     ('my', 'program', 'first'),
     ('program', 'first', 'my'),
     ('program', 'my', 'first')])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do this natively in Python...

```
def recurse_combinations(used, unused, dic ):

    if len(unused) == 0:#If unused is empty we are done
        dic[used]= True #Lets store the result and stop recursing
        return

    for i in range(len(unused)):
        #keep recursing by going through 'unused' characters and adding them to 'used'. Now lets take out the single character we are now using from 'unused'
        recurse_combinations( used + unused[i], unused[:i]+unused[i+1:], dic  )


def recurse_combinations_start( word="my first program"):
    dic = {}

    recurse_combinations( "" , word, dic)

    pprint ( dic.keys() )
    print len(dic.keys())
```

Simply call this recurse_combinations_start() and change the word you want to use